# Push bone to surface of mesh

Tags: armature, constraints, dynamic

I am wondering if it is possible without physics to have an armature bone be dynamically "pushed" away based on mesh surface.

I know something like that is possible with the Limit Distance Constraint and Clamp Region set to "Outside", but that only works around the origin point of the target object and thus only with spheres.

For example, lets say I have such a setup:
[image]

Now I want the bone to essentially move dynamically "up" the mesh if I move the mesh to the left with the end result being something like this:
[image]

If I keep moving the mesh the bone should snap back into its original position:
[image]

I am probably overthinking this, but I can't come up with a simple solution.

Comment: You can use a shrinkwrap constraint.  In your pics, for that exact problem, using it on project mode (project +Y) would be appropriate.